# let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ be such that $f(x)=0$ except at finitely many points. Show the integral of $f(x)$ equals zero.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm working on the following problem:

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ be such that $f(x)=0$ except at finitely many points. Show that $\int_a^b{f(x)}dx=0$.

Am I pointed in the wrong direction for wanting to use contradiction? If I assume $$\int_a^b{f(x)}dx\neq0$$ then can I assume $f$ must contain a variable x such that $f$ is not a constant? Is it that simple? I'm missing a lot of connections.

Comment: What does "$f$ must contain a variable $x$ such that $f$ is not a constant" mean?

Comment: Are you studying Riemann integration or Lebesgue integration ? If it is Lebesgue you have the "almost everywhere" (a.e.) that allows you to modify a function on a set of measure 0, in particular a finite set without modifying the integral.

Comment: Using the riemann sum definition, partition the interval and shrink the partitions around the finitely many points containing $0$. Then, as you take the limit, the contribution of these points will go to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Take a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ and calculate the upper and lower Riemann sum with respect to this partition:

$$
\begin{align*}
L_P(f)=&\sum_{I \in P} \inf_I(f) |I|\\
U_P(f)=&\sum_{I \in P} \sup_I(f) |I|
\end{align*}
$$

Then $f$ is Riemann integrable if $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\;\exists P_0$ such that $|U_P(f)-L_P(f)|<\epsilon$ for all refinements $P$ of $P_0$.

Now let $M = 2\max\{|f(x)|\}$. Then $U_P(f)-L_P(f) \leq  M \left|\bigcup_{\{I|\sup_I(|f|)>0\}} \right|\rightarrow 0$ as the total length of any finite number of intervals in $P$ goes to 0 as you keep refining the partition of $[a,b]$.